# Having trouble converting this require statement into an import statement

Tags: javascript, import

I have a require statement in my script.

`const packageJsonVersion = require('../package.json').version;`

If I try and run the script I get an error saying I need to convert it to an import statement.

I changed the code to `import { version as packageJsonVersion } from '../package.json'` but when I run the script I get the following error.

`TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".json" for /home/alex/_code/connect/package.json`

I'm not sure how to get around this.

Comment: Because it's JSON and not a module? Doesn't it have to be parsed first before you can extract the property information?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what environment you're doing this in.

- Right now, browsers don't natively support JSON modules (though [it's coming](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-json-modules)).
- If you're doing this with a bundler, you need to be sure to tell the bundler how to handle the `.json` extension.
- If you're doing this in Node.js, [you need the JSON module notation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#json-modules) (`assert {type: "json"}`).

Separately, though, JSON modules won't support named exports (this is mentioned by both links above). You'll have to import the default and then use the `version` property on it:

```
import data from "../package.json" assert { type: "json" };
const packageJsonVersion = data.version;
```